# What happened to Dart's Expect?

Tags: dart

Some Dart code I'm maintaining uses Expect.equals, Expect.isTrue, and others.  Expect no longer appears to be part of Dart.  There is no mention of its disappearance in [the changelog](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).  Questions:

1. Where should I be looking when there is a breaking change such as this?
2. Every year for the past five years all my Dart applications stop compiling as a result of core language changes (like string concatenation being removed, or dart:uri disappearing).  How do Dart programmers handle this?

Comment: I'm using Dart since 2013 and I can't remember seeing such code. Where did you import it from?

Comment: The closest to the code you mention from the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test package.

Comment: To 2) Just update the code or use a mature language like Jave where only very little changes over the years anymore.

Comment: The things you mention are about 5 years old, the language was in very early stage (pre alpha) back then. It was clearly communicated back then that breaking chages are to be expected, not at least by semantic versioning and the used version numbers.

Answer (score 5):

The `Expect` class still exists in the "expect" package in the `pkg/expect` directory of the Dart repository. It was built as an internal test tool for the Dart project, and it has never been [released on pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages?q=expect). The class was part of `dart:core` before the Dart 1.0 release, and was removed in April 2013 ([commit](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/343fa26d653379872ce754bf39a1c26985467347)), which predates the changelog.

It's a deliberately simple helper package because it is used to test the language and platform itself. A bug in the platform can make the test package fail and hide the bug, so the fewer features the test framework uses, the more trustworthy the platform tests are. 
There are a few parts of the expect package that are particular to testing Dart implementations (some annotations used by dart2js).

When you are not building a Dart platform, you should be able to use the [test package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test). It has many more features and better usability, and you won't have to worry about it not working because of you introducing bugs into the platform.

If you want to use the expect package, you still can (it's open source), but it's not intended or supported for end-users.